# Reset quantity to zero if one item is purchased

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm going in circles trying to figure this out...

I am trying to reset the Qty column to zero, on 5 items if customer has purchased the 5th item.  Another column must be respected as well, whether or not the item was purchased or returned. This column's value must be "3337", and I only want to reset the QTY field to zero on lines where the purchased / returned column value = 3337

An example table:

```
Customer | Item # | Qty | Purchased / returned 
1        | 1      | 1   | 3337
1        | 2      | 2   | 3337
1        | 3      | 1   | 3337
1        | 4      | 1   | 3337
1        | 5      | 1   | 3337
1        | 1      | 1   | 1034
2        | 1      | 1   | 3337
2        | 3      | 1   | 3337
2        | 4      | 1   | 3337
2        | 2      | 1   | 3337
3        | 1      | 1   | 3337
4        | 1      | 1   | 3337
```

In my example table, only customer # 1 has achieved the 5th item, so I want to reset the QTY field to 0 but only on the lines where the purchased / returned column = 1034

The result should look like this.

```
Customer | Item # | Qty | Purchased / returned 
1        | 1      | 0   | 3337
1        | 2      | 0   | 3337
1        | 3      | 0   | 3337
1        | 4      | 0   | 3337
1        | 5      | 0   | 3337
1        | 1      | 1   | 1034
2        | 1      | 1   | 3337
2        | 3      | 1   | 3337
2        | 4      | 1   | 3337
2        | 2      | 1   | 3337
3        | 1      | 1   | 3337
4        | 1      | 1   | 3337
```

Comment: You want implement it in a stored procedure or in a trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making some assumptions on datatypes and simplified column  names:

```
UPDATE MyTable
 set Qty = 0
 where Purchased = 3337
  and Customer in (--  All purchasers of 3337 who got to Item 5
                   select Customer
                    from MyTable
                    where Item = 5
                     and Purchased = 3337
                     and Qty = 1)  --  Line added in after initial post
```

Comment: This looks pretty close, except that it doesn't validate that the QTY field = 1. When I do a test query right now, I see 26 customers that have met the requirements. When I run your query it resets 131 customers because it is seeing customers who have "item = 5", but most of those customers that have item = 5 also have qty = 0 already. I don't want to reset these customers, only the customers where item 5's QTY is = to 1.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I added the same line at the end myself and it worked out.